# How to make html table vertically scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, css

[see jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oguxek/edit#javascript,html,live)

I have to make my html table vertically scrollable.
I have used below code on `tbody` tag but its doesn't work for me

```
 <tbody style="height: 100px; overflow: auto">
```

Comment: Maybe you should use <th> instead of <td> in your <thead>. Can't really help you but I'm sure you can find your answer on an example like that [CSS Scrollable Table with Fixed header](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html)

Comment: Use a div to wrap your table and define overflow declaration in div wrapped table.

Comment: you can do this by using @Ashlash and my answer..

Comment: Nikhil, Add 'display:block' to tbody and thead

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Why don't you place your table in a div?

```
<div style="height:100px;overflow:auto;">

 ... Your code goes here ...

</div>
```

Comment: A div does not have table semantics, and does not solve -- apart multiple divs -- the issue of a scrolling table body behind a table header.

Comment: To add to @Javarome's comment (because I didn't understand it as a front-end newbie): when the solution above scrolls, the table header will disappear.

This is not what you want most of the time. Ideally the header should stay in place as you scroll the rows of the table, so you can see the data in the rows and their headers at the same time.

Comment: on this way, how to create sticky header btw?

Comment: you can designate sticky on your <th> elements. Your HTML should be: <table><thead><tr><th>This is table header (then close the tags) and your css should be th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;} Note that designating the <thead> to be sticky does not always work cuz of some bug (as mentioned in some other stackoverflow thread)

Comment: Why is this accepted answer? OP asks about table, not `div`.

Answer (score 18):

Just add the display:block to the thead > tr and tbody. check the below example

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: hi im pretty dumb. how do i use the example? All i see is the working table on that website :(

Comment: This technique doesn't work if any of the columns don't have a width specified. :-(

Comment: @stackPusher right click the page and go to "View page source". You will be able to check out what the author did.

Answer (score 15):

Try this one.. It is working... Here [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/iveroj/13/edit)

```
table tbody { height:300px; overflow-y:scroll; display:block; }
table thead { display:block; }
```

Comment: That won't work. Add borders around your table cells and you'll see why. http://jsbin.com/iveroj/114/edit

Comment: The method will work if you account for the width of the scroll bar as part of the header, which is more than likely more trouble than it's worth.  Basically you'd need to make the header 21px wider than the body to account for the scroll bar width, at least in the Chrome 34.0.1847.131 m running in Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery plugin is probably the best option. http://farinspace.com/jquery-scrollable-table-plugin/

To fixing header you can check this post

[**Fixing Header of GridView or HtmlTable**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/03/fixing-header-of-gridview-or-htmltable.html) (there might be issue that this should work in IE only)

CSS for fixing header

```
div#gridPanel 
{
   width:900px;
   overflow:scroll;
   position:relative;
}


div#gridPanel th
{  
   top: expression(document.getElementById("gridPanel").scrollTop-2);
   left:expression(parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollLeft);
   position: relative;
   z-index: 20;
  }

<div height="200px" id="gridPanel" runat="server" scrollbars="Auto" width="100px">
table..
</div>
```

or

Very good post is here for this

[**How to Freeze Columns Using JavaScript and HTML.**](http://www.massless.org/_tests/grid1/?s=1&r=40&c=40)

or

No its not possible but you can make use of div and put table in div

```
<div style="height: 100px; overflow: auto">
  <table style="height: 500px;">
   ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: it works but header is also scroll vertical i have to make tbody  scrollable with fixed header thead..if u want to html code then i put jsbin.

Comment: it is not gridvies its just html table ..in css get error expression not valid attribute for top

Comment: @Nikhil - this will work in IE only its better you make use of jQuery plugin link is given by me at top in anwwer will help you to achieve your task easily..

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is strictly separate your table into two different tables - header and body:

```
<div class="header">
  <table><tr><!-- th here --></tr></table>
</div>

<div class="body">
  <table><tr><!-- td here --></tr></table>
</div>

.body {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto
}
```

If your table has a big width (more than screen width), then you have to add scroll events for horizontal scrolling header and body synchroniously.

You should never touch table tags (table, tbody, thead, tfoot, tr) with CSS properties **display** and **overflow**. Dealing with DIV wrappers is much more preferable.

Comment: +1, though using "body" and "header" as css class strikes me as a bit odd!

Comment: Separating the table header from its content like this seems like bad practice. That's what `tbody` and `thead` is for.

Comment: The columns will never line up correctly without explicitly defining each width. This doesn't seem like a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

Hi try with this overflow-y: scroll. I hope it may helps you

Comment: overflow-y is not a known css property name and fails

Comment: it is now.  overflow-y is overflow only in the vertical direction.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution (in Spring with Thymeleaf and jQuery):

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:tiles="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body>
        <div id="objects" th:fragment="ObjectList">
            <br/>
            <div id='cap'>
                <span>Objects</span>
            </div>
            <div id="hdr">
                <div>
                    <div class="Cell">Name</div>
                        <div class="Cell">Type</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bdy">
                <div th:each="object : ${objectlist}">
                        <div class="Cell" th:text="${object.name}">name</div>
                        <div class="Cell" th:text="${object.type}">type</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
#cap span {
    display: table-caption;
    border:2px solid;
    font-size: 200%;
    padding: 3px;
}
#hdr {
    display:block;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:0;
    border:2px solid;
}
#bdy {
    display:block;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:0;
    border:2px solid;
}
#objects #bdy {
    height:300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
#hdr div div{
    margin-left:-3px;
    margin-right:-3px;
    text-align: right;
}
#hdr div:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
#bdy div div {
    margin-left:-3px;
    margin-right:-3px;
    text-align: right;
}
#bdy div div:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
.Cell
{
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = ['#objects'];
    divs.forEach(function(div)
    {
        if ($(div).length > 0)
        {
            var widths = [];
            var totalWidth = 0;
            $(div+' #hdr div div').each(function() {
                widths.push($(this).width())
            });
            $(div+' #bdy div div').each(function() {
                var col = $(this).index();
                if ( $(this).width() > widths[col] )
                {
                    widths[col] = $(this).width();
                }
            });
            $(div+' #hdr div div').each(function() {
                var newWidth = widths[$(this).index()]+5;
                $(this).css("width", newWidth);
                totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
            });
            $(div+' #bdy div div').each(function() {
                $(this).css("width", widths[$(this).index()]+5);
            });
            $(div+' #hdr').css("width", totalWidth);
            $(div+' #bdy').css("width", totalWidth+($(div+' #bdy').css('overflow-y')=='auto'?15:0));
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a work around.

http://jsfiddle.net/JJV59/2/

**[EDIT]**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

<table cellspacing="1" width="100%" bgcolor="#cccccc">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="70px">
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd" width="70px">
                <b>Time Slot&nbsp;</b>
            </td>
            <td class="csstablelisttd">
                <b>&nbsp;Patient Name</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<!-- THIS GIVES THE SCROLLER -->
<div style="height: 500px; overflow-y: auto">
    <table id="tableAppointment" cellspacing="1" width="100%" bgcolor="#cccccc">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="70px">
                    8:00AM
                </td>
                <td class="csstablelisttd" width="70px">
                    0
                </td>
                <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    <span>Name 1</span>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        9:00AM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        10:00AM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        11:00AM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        12:00PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        01:00PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        02:00PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        03:00PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        04:00PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        05:00PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        06:00PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        07:00PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        15
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        30
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        45
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd" valign="top" width="90px">
                        08:00PM
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        0
                    </td>
                    <td class="csstablelisttd">
                        <span></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u putt whole html in ur answer .in jsfiddle i unabele to get html

Comment: apologies, mis read your previous comment, updated the answer now

Comment: u taje diffrent tabel for header and body it should not like that i want in one table header and body because my javascript functionality depend on thead

Answer (score -1):

An old question, but here is a decent solution for those looking for a quick OOB solution which does not rely on `JQuery` or `JS`.  The height can be whatever best suits your needs.  The OP had `100px` in his example, so that's what I've made it here.  You may need to tweak the style to specific use cases, but it should at least solve the OP's issue, and help others.

CSS:

```
table.fixed-header thead tr {
    display:    block;
}

table.fixed-header tbody {
    display:    block;
    overflow:   auto;
    height:     100px;
    width:      100%;
}
```

html:

```
<table class=fixed-header>
    <thead>
        <tr">
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

I fought with this one for a while. My goal was to have a table with headers where the widths of the each header column was the the same as the corresponding body column and was the minimum size necessary to fit the data. also the body data was scrollable underneath header.

I solved this by using divs and not tables. Each "table" was a div with the header being a div of divs and the body being a div of divs. I used the style as indicated by @sushil above. I added a bit of javascript/jQuery to balance the columns. Maybe 20-30 lines.

Unfortunately I lost the code and have to rebuild it. I know this is a bit old, but maybe it will help someone else.